# How to split a large .csv file using dask?

Tags: python, csv, dask, aws-batch

I am trying to use `dask` in order to split a huge tab-delimited file into smaller chunks on an AWS Batch array of 100,000 cores.

In AWS Batch each core has a unique environment variable `AWS_BATCH_JOB_ARRAY_INDEX` ranging from 0 to 99,999 (which is copied into the `idx` variable in the snippet below). Thus, I am trying to use the following code:

```
import os
import dask.dataframe as dd

idx = int(os.environ["AWS_BATCH_JOB_ARRAY_INDEX"])

df = dd.read_csv(f"s3://main-bucket/workdir/huge_file.tsv", sep='\t')
df = df.repartition(npartitions=100_000)
df = df.partitions[idx]

df = df.persist() # this call isn't needed before calling to df.to_csv (see comment by Sultan)
df = df.compute() # this call isn't needed before calling to df.to_csv (see comment by Sultan)
df.to_csv(f"/tmp/split_{idx}.tsv", sep="\t", index=False)
print(idx, df.shape, df.head(5))
```

Do I need to call `presist` and/or `compute` before calling `df.to_csv`?

Comment: Hi 0x90 it is not quite clear what is idx used for. How big is the file you want to split? I did a similar thing using a single machine only. In that case I was able to split a 17GB file into several smaller ones using a single machine with 4 cores and 16GB of RAM.

Comment: @rpanai file with 1TB. It does work, but I want to make sure I do the right thing. As I call persist and compute in tandem. Not sure both are needed. Idx as I said is a unique integer between 0 and 99,999

Comment: Are you saving it locally or to S3? If you don't mind I can show you how I splitted. I notices that if you save to parquet it's faster

Comment: @rpanai s3 please share your approach. I'd love to see it.

Comment: Not sure what I added is a proper answer but you could have a look.

Comment: Neither `persist` nor `compute` are needed before writing with `.to_csv`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I have to split a big file into multiple smaller ones, I simply run the following code.

## Read and repartition

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_csv("file.csv")
df = df.repartition(npartitions=100)
```

## Save to csv

```py
o = df.to_csv("out_csv/part_*.csv", index=False)
```

## Save to parquet

```py
o = df.to_parquet("out_parquet/")
```

Here you can use `write_metadata_file=False` if you want to avoid metadata.

Few notes:

- I don't think you really need persist and compute as you can directly save to disk. When you have problems like memory error is safer to save to disk rather than compute.
- I found using parquet format at least 3x faster than csv when it's time to write.

Comment: My bad. Fixed it!

Comment: Just I don't like to have printed out all the filenames are written.